# How to change a date format in CAML

Tags: development, caml-query, caml

I got a wrong date format to a CAML. I have got (**yyyy-mm-dd**) and must to be understand by CAML to the format(**dd-mm-yyyy**), how can I do this. I tried by String.Format("{0:yyyy-mm-dd}", dateISO1);, but it doesn't help. Here is my code:

```
  private void WyswietlanieUrlopow(SPWeb witryna1, DayRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        // Obszar odpowiedzialny za wyświetlenie i wypisanie dni urlopowych, jak też dni chorobowych pracowników


        //string FullQueryUrlap = "<Where><And><Geq><FieldRef Name='{0}' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>{1}</Value></Geq><And><Leq><FieldRef Name='{2}' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>{3}</Value></Leq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Nazwisko' /><Value Type='Note'>{4}</Value></Eq></And></And></Where>";
       // string FullQueryUrlap = "<Where><And><Geq><FieldRef Name='{0}' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>{1}</Value></Geq><And><Leq><FieldRef Name='{2}' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>{3}</Value></Leq><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Nazwisko' /><Value Type='Note'>{4}</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Imie' /><Value Type='Note'>{5}</Value></Eq></And></And></And></Where>";
        string FullQueryUrlap = "<Where><And><Geq><FieldRef Name='{0}' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>{1}</Value></Geq><And><Leq><FieldRef Name='{2}' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>{3}</Value></Leq><Eq><FieldRef Name='LoginName' /><Value Type='Text'>{4}</Value></Eq></And></And></Where>";
        string dateISO1 = SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(e.Day.Date.ToUniversalTime().AddHours(1.0));
        Convert.ToDateTime(dateISO1);
        string dateISO1con = String.Format("{0:yyyy-mm-dd}", dateISO1);
        string dateISO2 = SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(e.Day.Date.ToUniversalTime().AddHours(2.0));
        Convert.ToDateTime(dateISO2);
        string dateISO2con = String.Format("{0:dd-mm-yyyy}", dateISO2);

        int spacja = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.IndexOf(" ");

        var queryPoszczegolnyUrlop = new SPQuery();
        queryPoszczegolnyUrlop.Query = String.Format(FullQueryUrlap, "DataKon", dateISO1con, "DataPoc", dateISO2con, DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text);
        queryPoszczegolnyUrlop.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='DataPoc' /><FieldRef Name='DataKon' />";
        queryPoszczegolnyUrlop.ViewFieldsOnly = true;
```

Comment: I like using [Moment.js][1] instead of messing with SPUtility.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17093796/date-formatting-with-without-moment-js

Answer (score 1):

You got wrong date format to a CAML. The date format (yyyy-mm-dd) and must to be understand by CAML to the format(dd-mm-yyyy). You can do this by String.Format("{0:yyyy-mm-dd}", dateISO1);, but it doesn't help. Here is my code:
  private void WyswietlanieUrlopow(SPWeb witryna1, DayRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        // Obszar odpowiedzialny za wyświetlenie i wypisanie dni urlopowych, jak też dni chorobowych pracowników

```
    //string FullQueryUrlap = "<Where><And><Geq><FieldRef Name='{0}' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>{1}</Value></Geq><And><Leq><FieldRef Name='{2}' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>{3}</Value></Leq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Nazwisko' /><Value Type='Note'>{4}</Value></Eq></And></And></Where>";
   // string FullQueryUrlap = "<Where><And><Geq><FieldRef Name='{0}' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>{1}</Value></Geq><And><Leq><FieldRef Name='{2}' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>{3}</Value></Leq><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Nazwisko' /><Value Type='Note'>{4}</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Imie' /><Value Type='Note'>{5}</Value></Eq></And></And></And></Where>";
    string FullQueryUrlap = "<Where><And><Geq><FieldRef Name='{0}' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>{1}</Value></Geq><And><Leq><FieldRef Name='{2}' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>{3}</Value></Leq><Eq><FieldRef Name='LoginName' /><Value Type='Text'>{4}</Value></Eq></And></And></Where>";
    string dateISO1 = SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(e.Day.Date.ToUniversalTime().AddHours(1.0));
    Convert.ToDateTime(dateISO1);
    string dateISO1con = String.Format("{0:yyyy-mm-dd}", dateISO1);
    string dateISO2 = SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(e.Day.Date.ToUniversalTime().AddHours(2.0));
    Convert.ToDateTime(dateISO2);
    string dateISO2con = String.Format("{0:dd-mm-yyyy}", dateISO2);

    int spacja = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.IndexOf(" ");

    var queryPoszczegolnyUrlop = new SPQuery();
    queryPoszczegolnyUrlop.Query = String.Format(FullQueryUrlap, "DataKon", dateISO1con, "DataPoc", dateISO2con, DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text);
    queryPoszczegolnyUrlop.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='DataPoc' /><FieldRef Name='DataKon' />";
    queryPoszczegolnyUrlop.ViewFieldsOnly = true;
```

Comment: This helped me resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:
[Query list with CAML - DateTime column](http://wyldesharepoint.blogspot.com/2009/07/query-list-with-caml-datetime-column.html)

Use this:
`SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(dateISO2)`

I hope this helps

Comment: But Arsalan i Used this :  `string dateISO2 = SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(e.Day.Date.ToUniversalTime().AddHours(2.0));` Please look at code :)

Comment: What is the problem in above ??

Comment: I getting the date from External List yyyy-mm-dd, and I want to get in format dd-mm-yyyy, because only in this format date is understood my dates.